# How to connect in a domain via VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

So my PC is in a domain, but my virtual machine does not see it. I give the credentials in the Log in screen and I get this in the guest OS:

[image]

My host OS is Windows 7 and my guest OS is Windows XP and I use Oracle VirtualBox.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly linked all the virtual adapters?
If you can't ping the domain controller server, you should check your (virtual) cables.
Also, try to add the pc to a domain in the control panel.

Comment: I don't know how to , i guess from here : Devices --> Network adapters?

Comment: @Vasilisfoo you need to create the virtual adapters in virtual box [manual ch.6: networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)